# When running vpnc in docker, get 'Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system'

Tags: permissions, routing, linux-networking, docker, vpn-client

I'm trying to run console `Cisco VPN client` in Docker.
I start the container like that:

```
docker run -it -v /srv/vpn/keys/:/root/keys/ --network=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN  --device=/dev/net/tun -v /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun vpn-vpnc-client_img
```

And then run the `vpnc` client inside Docker container

```
vpnc-connect /root/keys/vpnc.conf --local-port 0
```

It produces the following output:

```
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system
VPNC started in background (pid: 257)...
```

`vpnc` connects and creates proper routes, so VPN seems to work. My concern is the warning message.
According to the documentation, for `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush`

> Writing to this file results in a flush of the routing cache.

I don't understand this statement. Is it critical that routing cache did not get flushed?

Also, as I understand, I can issue

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
```

manually after start of the container. But I use `monit` inside docker container to restart the `vpnc` if connection gets lost. Can I bind mount `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush`  from host inside container somehow, and issue the command to flush routing cache from monit script inside container?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no, I did not find it

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no fine granular capability (for `--add-cap`) which enables that. So `--privileged` is the only solution that works for me.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am one of the core developers of OpenConnect and maintainers of the [vpnc-script](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts) — which is used by *both* vpnc and OpenConnect for routing and DNS configuration.

This error message actually comes from the `vpnc-script`, not from `vpnc` itself, and…

1. This error *doesn't matter at all*. It come from the command `ip -4 route flush cache`, which triggers IPv4 route flushing, which is an [unnecessary, deprecated, no-op in modern Linux kernels](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/merge_requests/30).

   We retain it only for backwards-compatibility, in case someone somewhere is running `vpnc`/OpenConnect on an annnnnnnnnnnnnnnnncieeeeeeent Linux kernel.
2. We suppressed the error message in [a 2019 change to the standard `vpnc-script`](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/commit/33b5d8198b5f375418379e483031d3ec9019225d).

   If you simply replace your `vpnc-script` with [the latest version](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/blob/master/vpnc-script), the error will go away.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is [no granular capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to be used with `--add-cap`, so you will have to run the container in privileged mode using `--privileged` in order to get rid of that warning.

Comment: This isn't necessary a solution. Its a workaround since now the docker is running as root in order to gain the necessary host permissions in order to achieve the result.

Comment: Its possible the future kernels will have this fix. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't allow for this yet: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20190624132923.16792-1-christian@brauner.io/

Comment: If it's an Ubuntu host, then either AppArmor or Docker's overmounting of certain proc elements might cause this; this isn't necessarily something related (only) to capabilities. You need to look at the full security stack, which is complex.